# Authentication when making curl requests

Tags: curl

I don't fully understand how curl works and what it lacks to download a file. Through Chrome, everything loads correctly.

curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" --proxy "http://mylogin:mypass@proxyadress:port" -u  "http://e-trust.gosuslugi.ru/CA/DownloadTSL?schemaVersion=0"

When executing the command, I receive the following error:

Sorry, you are not currently allowed to request http://e-trust.gosuslugi.ru/CA/DownloadTSL? from this cache until you have authenticated yourself

How to understand what kind of authorization is needed? When opening the link in Chrome, the file loads correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This URL returns 307/HSTS Redirect response code which is handled from the browser.

curl request is failing with timeout.

[image]

To download the file with curl I copied the request from chrome, and you can use this:

```
curl 'https://e-trust.gosuslugi.ru/CA/DownloadTSL' \
  -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,bg;q=0.8' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'DNT: 1' \
  -H 'Pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' \
  -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="113", "Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'sec-gpc: 1' \
  --compressed > ~/Downloads/tsl.xml
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 11.0M    0 11.0M    0     0  1000k      0 --:--:--  0:00:11 --:--:-- 1032k
```